# Wireguard not able to connect after a few minutes

Tags: debian, vpn, wireguard

I set up an Wireguard Network with 5 Peers. The connection between all of those works. But with one peer I have to ping him or have something else that keeps the connection alive. If I don't use the peer over Wireguard for a few minutes, I have to restart the wireguard interface to get a connection again.

The client is a Virtual Machine and runs on KVM / Debian 11.

The Webserver on the public ip is always accessible.

Answer (score 7):

Try using `PersistentKeepalive = 25` option in `[Peer]` configuration block on both sides, for example:

Server:

```
[Peer] 
PublicKey = _REDACTED_
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Client:

```
[Peer]
PublicKey = _REDACTED_
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = server:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

Quote from [wg](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/wg.8.html) man page:

> PersistentKeepalive — a seconds interval, between 1 and
> 65535 inclusive, of how often to send an authenticated
> empty packet to the peer for the purpose of keeping a
> stateful firewall or NAT mapping valid persistently. For
> example, if the interface very rarely sends traffic, but
> it might at anytime receive traffic from a peer, and it is
> behind NAT, the interface might benefit from having a
> persistent keepalive interval of 25 seconds. If set to 0
> or "off", this option is disabled. By default or when
> unspecified, this option is off. Most users will not need
> this. Optional.

For more details please refer to: https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/#nat-and-firewall-traversal-persistence